# How to start pm2 website using jenkins on AWS ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, amazon-s3

I set up **Jenkins**, **pm2** on **AWS ubuntu** server. I had a website **A** that built by **jenkins**. The **jenkins** then will start that website by **pm2** in the configured shell. However, only I start the website by logging on to the **ubuntu** server manually and run `pm2 start A` can make the website running.

The problem seems that **pm2** started by user **jenkins** will **not** be visible by the outside world. Only started by user **ubuntu** (via ssh ubuntu@myubuntuserver) can be effectively public.

Why and how can I make **jenkins** start **pm2** automatically?

Comment: any answers on this ? have the same problem...

Comment: @L.querter, I finally found out the reason, and I answered my own question.  Hope it can help you. :)

Comment: thank you ! do you use NGINX on the jenkins user to serve the page ? or how do you connect your pm2 in jenkins with other user services ?

Comment: Yes I use nginx to do the proxy. I `pm2 start webSiteA` on port 8888, and I use nginx to proxy the port 80 to 8888 listen on a specific domain name.

Comment: I didn't quite get your point on the latter question. What do you mean by other user services and the connecting from pm2 to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the jenkins has already started pm2 automatically. Why you can't see it via `pm2 status` is because you logged in to the server with another user.

By `sudo su jenkins` you can switch to the `jenkins` user and then you can see them by `pm2 status`.

Answer (score 2):

Its late but just help someone in need:

Issue: pm2 would have been installed with ***ubuntu*** user or ***root***, which Jenkins can't access

- Login to Jenkins: `sudo su jenkins` (if password is required, set
  password from root user `sudo passwd jenkins`)
- Install PM2: `npm i -g pm2`

Now, Jenkins should be able to run pm2